# creating a function; scanf and char issues

Tags: c, function, scanf, cs50

I am at the very initial stage of learning programming. I working with a program that uses self-made function. I don't understand my mistakes. I would be grateful for your help. Please, do me a favor and answer using methods that are commensurate with the primitive stage I am at. I am leaving comments I've written, so you can see what I am trying to achieve by this or that code line.

```
/* Prints a user's name */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// prototype
void PrintName(char name); 

/* this is a hint for the C saying that this function will be later specified */

int main(void)
{
    char name[50];

    printf("Your name: ");
    scanf ("%49s", name); /* limit the number of characters to 50 */
    PrintName(name);
}

// Says hello to someone by name

void PrintName(char name)
{
    printf("hello, %s\n", name);
}
```

I get these error messages:

```
function0.c: In function ‘main’:
function0.c:14: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘PrintName’ makes integer from pointer without a cast
function0.c: In function ‘PrintName’:
function0.c:21: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’
function0.c:21: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’
```

The function PrintName is based on the previous program I took from the course (and adopted it to C):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char name[40];

    printf ("Type a name:  ");
    scanf ("%39s", name);

    printf ("%s", name); 

    printf("\n");
 }
```

This last program works perfectly.
What mistake do I make in my original program? If I understand correctly, there is a problem with my PrintName function.

The initial program that prints a name is a modified version of CS50 program that uses CS50 library:

```
// Prints a user's name

#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

// prototype
void PrintName(string name); 

int main(void)
{
    printf("Your name: ");
    string s = GetString(); //GetString is the same as scanf; it takes input from the user
    PrintName(s);            
}

// Says hello to someone by name

void PrintName(string name)
{
    printf("hello, %s\n", name); 
}
```

Given "string" is "char" in C, I replace string with char in my program. 
Thank you!

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what's wrong: `printf` expects a `char *` for the `%s` specifier, you supply a `char`. Your `PrintName` expects a `char`, but you supply a `char *` (or more specifically a `char[50]` that decays to a `char *`).

Comment: Thank you. I am not yet familiar with the difference between char and char*. If I understand you correctly, %s requires char*.  I saw a test program that has %s in scanf and the same char array: #include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char initial = ' ';
  char name[80] = { 0 };
  char age[4] = { 0 };

  printf("Enter your first initial: ");
  scanf("%c", &initial );
  printf("Enter your first name: ");
  scanf("%s", name );

  if(initial != name[0])
    printf("\n%s,you got your initial wrong.", name);
  else
    printf("\nHi, %s. Your initial is correct. Well done!", name );

Comment: sorry! have no idea how to post a program in comments. my post now looks bad.

Comment: A `char` is a character while `char*` is a pointer to a `char`. Surround code with backticks (\`) to format as code. Yes, `%s` in both `scanf` and `printf` expects a `char*`. Just keep in mind that whenever you pass an array to a function, you actually pass the address of the first element of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Your function `PrintName` is waiting for a char as parameter but you give a `char[]` that's why you see this :

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘PrintName’ makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

To give a `char[]` as parameter you need to change your function like this :

```
void PrintName(char *name);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use char* instead of char, as an argument of your function. Char is one symbol, while char* is pointer to a string.

Answer (score 1):

Change `void PrintName (char name);` to `void PrintName (char *name);` or to `void PrintName (char name[]);`

Currently this function receives one character called name. You want it to receive an array of chars.

Answer (score 1):

```
 void PrintName(char name);
```

You function expects a `character variable` to be passed but instead you pass a `char array`. Thus it leads to error.

Moreover, `%s` in `printf` will expect a `char *` and you pass a `char`,thus leading to another problem.

To correct you program declare and define function with parameter as follows-

```
void PrintName(char *name);
```

or

```
void PrintName(char name[]);
```

Both will work.

Comment: Thank you everyone! Now it is clear. Thank you for the help!